# How to play two or more videos side by side in a syncronized fashion in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video

I have two (or more) video files that I want to play side by side. I could do that simply by opening them in two seperate windows, but that would also seperate all the controls (play/pause/forward/...). I want to play them in a synchronized fashion so that pause/forwarding/... works on both videos simultaneously so that they always stay at the same timecode and they don't go out of sync. How would I accomplish that in Linux?

This is needed for viewing only, so compositing them into a new video file first should be avoided if possible, but if there isn't an easy way to do that, I welcome answers doing it with composition as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Describing Florian's solutions:

If your want play 3 videos:

1) make 3 pipes

```
$ mkfifo cmds1 cmds2 cmds3
```

2) run 3 mplayers reading commands from pipes

```
$ mplayer -slave -input file=cmds1 -quiet file1.mp4
$ mplayer -slave -input file=cmds2 -quiet file2.mp4
$ mplayer -slave -input file=cmds3 -quiet file3.mp4
```

3) use `tee` to write to pipes simultaneously.

```
$ tee cmds1 cmds2 > cmds3
```

4) now enter commands like `pause`, ...

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it could be done writing a simple frontend driving two MPlayer instances in slave mode, see *-slave* in the mplayer manpage

Answer (score 0):

I found newer answers to this old question that seem easier. Media players (mpv worked for me) can do this as shown in
[llogan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1325668/1001420) to [How to play multiple videos side-by-side synchronized?](https://superuser.com/questions/139549/how-to-play-multiple-videos-side-by-side-synchronized)