# Synchronise the playback of two different videos in VLC

Tags: video, sync, vlc-media-player

So I have two different videos, which I want to play at the same and be able to pause, stop, rewind forward/backward, ... so that this happens on both of them at the same time.

How could I achieve this (I prefer VLC, but other not overly involved methods will do too) ?

So far, I have done this by starting two VLC instances, but this lacks the synchronization, which is quite inconvenient.

Also, I have found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/139549/how-to-play-multiple-videos-side-by-side-synchronized), which seems to be quite close to what I want, but the answer given there does not solve my problem.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: primarily Windows 7

Comment: You can do this in QuichTime 7 with keyboard shortcuts.