# Play two videos in sync as well as having seek in sync

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have two different videos. Now here's the thing, they have the same lengths, and they are related to each other. Is there a way that I can play these videos on at the same time using VLC and also have a unified seek bar, so that the times are the same for both, since one video is dependent on the other.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be in VLC? If not, please edit your post and remove that requirement (and tag.)

Comment: Okay, it does not have to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play multiple videos side-by-side synchronized?](http://superuser.com/questions/139549/how-to-play-multiple-videos-side-by-side-synchronized)

Answer (score 17):

If anyone is still interested in this the current version of VLC is able to do this very well without any kind of scripting or add-on. To accomplish this simply open VLC and select Media>Open Multiple Files. Inside the multiple file windows select add to add the first file. After this click on the, "Show more options," checkbox followed by the, "Play another media synchronously," checkbox at the bottom of the window. Select browse next to, "Extra media," to add the second file. Hit play and the two media files will play simultaneously with a single control window.

Comment: If a multiple question have identical answers, they should be flagged as duplicates, submitting the same identical answer multiple times is odd behavior.

Comment: This is perfect if there is a way to set the delay.

Comment: This used to work, but it doesn't anymore in VLC 3.0.1.

Comment: I don't even have a Media menu on my VLC (Version 3.0.4 Vetinari (Intel 64bit)) on mac...

Comment: Can't make it work on modern MacOS VLC :( Came up with own solution https://github.com/cardinalby/vlc-sync-play to listen to different audio tracks simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in VLC for mac (version 2.2.6 https://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.6/macosx/) using File > Advanced open file.

Comment: That should be approximately the same as [Ramhound's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1029986/86708), except there the menu item is called "Open Multiple Files."

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for playing more than two files in sync?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use `ffmpeg`. If you have two or more videos you can just stack them horizontally, vertically or in a grid using `ffmpeg` and then play it as a single video file. Here is a snippet of how you would stack two `mp4` files horizontally:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex hstack=inputs=2 stacked_output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any player that could do that, but you could merge the two video files together to achieve what you want. See questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293265/ffmpeg-2-videos-transcoded-and-side-by-side-in-1-frame

Answer (score 0):

I have recently solved it with mplayer and you can see the solution on superuser here: [master-slave with mplayer](https://superuser.com/questions/751184/how-to-sync-two-looping-videos-with-mplayer-and-upd/792635#792635)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoHotKey to achieve something similar though not perfect. I posted my answer to a question similar to yours [here](https://superuser.com/a/828224/381020)

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.  You're really providing a hint for where to find an answer rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[vlcsync](https://github.com/mrkeuz/vlcsync) - it syncs multiply `vlc` instances in background. After tried to find a solution, decide wrote my own. This is how the solution came about.

**Features:**

- play/pause/seek from any player
- tested on Linux/Windows

**Note:**

- Do NOT provide exactly frame-to-frame sync, but do it close as possible and applicable in many cases (see: [Limitations](https://github.com/mrkeuz/vlcsync#limitations))