# Compare 2 video files for 'cut' differences

Tags: video, comparison

I have 2 video files with the same content, but coming from a different source. They have a slight difference in 'cut', meaning one can be missing a shot compared to the other.

I have a subtitle file that is correctly timed for one file (call it A), and because of the different cut, a bit off for the other (call it B).

The thing is that A also has some hardcoded subs, while B is of better quality, without hardcoded subs.

I basically need to fix the timing of the subs to match B (which I can do easily using some subtitle editor software).

In order to do so, i need to locate the missing/additional shots between the 2 videos, so i know where to adjust the subs timings.

I can do this manually [by playing both files in VLC](https://superuser.com/a/1029989/267246), with a dichotomic search approach. This is realistic if i have only one pair of files, however i have 20 pair of files !

I would like to automate this search, and basically compare the 2 files at different points in time, and find where they diverge.

How can I do this?

Since file A has some hardcoded subs, the comparison method should be exact enough to detect content difference, but not too strict as not to be triggered by the hardcoded subs.

Comment: Question edited so it is not asking for software (which is off-topic)

Comment: How should the user accomplish this if not with software?? With his bare hands?