# How to play two videos side by side synchronized in VLC

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

I need to play two videos side by side synchronized in VLC. I found answer below but it just opens one window and when I right-click in the video and go video/audio I can switch between the video/audio which run both at the same time but it is still in one window so I see/hear only one at the time. Any idea what extra setting can cause this? Using VLC 3.0.4. on win7.

[How to play multiple videos side-by-side synchronized?](https://superuser.com/questions/139549/how-to-play-multiple-videos-side-by-side-synchronized)

P.S. I would comment on existing question but I do not have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 4):

The post in your link contains in a deleted answer, so you cannot see it
(not having enough reputation),
the recommendation to use the free player
[Kinovea](https://www.kinovea.org/).

This player can do compare and synchronize.
Even videos with heterogeneous frame-rates can be synchronized.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, thought VLC should be able to do this, I am trying to figure out why it does not work for me specifically. Tried changing a lot of probably unrelated settings as well and no luck so far.

Comment: VLC "Open Multiple Files" is recommended for merging files while streaming or converting, but not for side-by-side playing. I tried it and it only plays one video at a time. You should look for other solutions.

Comment: Interesting, maybe they changed the purpose of it in new versions, since it seemed to worked to people in that thread I linked (in older VLC) as well as I found youtube tutorials doing just that and it worked for them too (again probably in older versions). Anyway I will leave this open a while, mb someone will know what the problem is (some setting we both have enabled on default which should not be - something like that). Anyway thanks for the feedback.