# How can I play multiple videos in VLC with a specified delay between them?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, delay

I've just read the VLC-based answer to this question:

[How to play multiple videos side-by-side synchronized?](https://superuser.com/q/139549/122798)

... and it works for me. However, I now want to play one of the videos at a delay. How can I get VLC to do that? Can I specify this as part of the "input-slave" text in the window?

Comment: It's probably simplest to just buffer up the front of that video with black, so it starts at the same time & gets its own viewport space, rather than trying to jog the others aside later, which is going to cause viewport issues; shifting or resizing.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Part of the reason I want this is to decide how much black to put in...